# Two closely matching files: get corresponding lines?

Tags: diff, string-matching, difflib, file-comparison, sequence-alignment

I'm in a situation where I'm programmatically generating LaTeX code, and I want my Synctex to point to the correct lines in the original file.

The generation is basically doing template expansion, so the original files are nearly identical to the generated ones, but with some snippets expanded.

I'm wondering, is there a diff tool or library that will easily give me the line number of the original file that corresponds to a given line in the generated one? Can this be extracted from a normal Unix diff somehow?

This is part of a build script, so ideally something easy to run, like bash or python, is preferred to something that needs to be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Google’s diff-match-patch lib is a neat solution to questions like these: https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch